# Cannot Run Maven Google Standard App Engine 1.9.68 Archetype

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Trying to update to latest version 1.9.68 but cannot find dependencies. Pretty bad since it was released 12 days ago https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#october_25_2018

When running archetype:

```
> >mvn clean compile [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING] [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
> se.unityworks:standard-archetype:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
> 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
> unique: com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar -> duplicate
> declaration of version 1.9.68 @ line 50, column 17 [WARNING] [WARNING]
> It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten
> the stability of your build. [WARNING] [WARNING] For this reason,
> future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed
> projects. [WARNING] [WARNING] The project
> se.unityworks:standard-archetype:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites
> which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non
> maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the
> maven-enforcer-plugin. See
> https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
> [INFO] [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building standard-archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The POM for
> com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.68 is missing, no
> dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
> com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.9.68 is missing, no
> dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
> com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.9.68 is missing, no
> dependency information available [WARNING] The POM for
> com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:1.9.68 is missing, no
> dependency information available [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 0.520 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2018-11-06T10:42:06+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project standard-archetype: Could
> not resolve dependencies for project
> se.unityworks:standard-archetype:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
> com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.68 in
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
> Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
> enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
> the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It was not on the maven repository yet. So just wait or try to download it manually should be a better choice.